# How to configure Microsoft Clarity for localhost in Angular app

Tags: angular, ms-clarity

I'm trying to configure Microsoft Clarity to work on `localhost` in my Angular app.

When I created the new project on the Microsoft Clarity portal, I've set the URL to `localhost` (I've also tried with `localhost:4200` as well) and then I copied the script and pasted it in the `<header>` of `index.html` page but seems to do nothing (no `collect` calls in the network tab, no logs in the portal).

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Or Microsoft Clarity is not working with `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your website's real URL in the URL section, not the localhost address.
but you can test Microsoft Clarity in localhost using the same projectId.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34873451)